# PhpMy admin -> mysql - Declaration of foreign keys for company database

Tags: mysql

i am trying to create a database for business management in the company where i work.

I want to insert the customers in a list (roughly 200-250) and this is quite easy.
Then i want to create a payment list e.g. (transaction n#2758) including details

i need to create relationship between customers and payment (i have used a foreign key , using unique and primary key)

for every customer i want to have payment details like in the table structure proposed below

```
                  codtrans             value      type       customer n.
customer#028 ---> transaction no.001   200€       cash           028
                  transaction no.002.  ---        cash           028
                  transaction no.003   ----       other          028
```

for now i have created a foreign key in the payment primary key(customer number) to customer unique code. 
transaction code is set to unique but still unlinked.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the question ? what is the SQL query that ou have actually ?

Comment: do you want to...? could you show the query you write?

Comment: using mysql 5.5.27
xamp 1.8.1

Comment: using mysql 5.5.27
xamp 1.8.1
php 5.4.7
i want to exactly show the example as above:

selecting customer28 should return the list of every transaction the amount the type with date etc.

Comment: Payment table has 7 fields.
Customers table has 10 fields.
Assuming that a customer can pay more than once, we are in the case of one to many (corect me if wrong) then i should put the foreign key reference in the Customers table.

afterwards, i need to create more relationships : 
tecnical operations, orders, stickers so i need 3 tables and those should be linked to Customers.
Am i forced to do many - to - one relationship from customers to other tables??